# Statistics and distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

How do you know if a distribution fits the data you are analyzing?
For example, if I had data that based on my assumption can be distributed geometrically, how can I check that this distribution fits my data and how can I be sure that any model of this type will fit my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of hypothesis test you can perform to your data to check if it fits a given distribution. Here you are a list:
Bayesian information criterion
Kolmogorov–Smirnov test
Cramér–von Mises criterion
Anderson–Darling test
Shapiro–Wilk test
Chi-squared test
Akaike information criterion
Hosmer–Lemeshow test
Kuiper's test
Kernelized Stein discrepancy
Zhang's ZK, ZC and ZA tests
Moran test
Density Based Empirical Likelihood Ratio tests

In this [link](https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/identify-distribution-data/) it is explained a procedure to find the best distribution.

In particular, [here you are a paper](https://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1230&context=jmasm) explaining an example of how to measure the goodness of fit of a geometric distribution.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Can you compare the estimated probabilities (from the data) to theoretical probabilities from a given model of a distribution and make a judgement on if that model fits the data.

Comment: In essence I think that that is what these tests do, in a systematic way.

Comment: If you want you can upvote the answer